# How do I get this query string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I get the following query in javascript?  It's important that we target search_query specifically.

```
search.php?search_query=flowers
```

None of the answers tell you how to specifically get the search query.

UPDATE: the answer can be found here - http://kcwebprogrammers.blogspot.com/2010/07/javascript-to-get-parameter-from-url.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.search` will give you the entire search string including the `?`. Can you take it from there?

Comment: This seems more a comment than an answer...

Comment: No, this is a sufficient answer. It requires OP to put some work into it, but it should be enough.

Comment: This answer has a lot more substance than the question...